# C3 chart fill does not work when using a variable for data.types

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I Have a line C3 chart I wish to fill,m but the name of the data fields is not fixed, I have it in a variable.

So, using the sample [here](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html), the following DOES fill fine

```
        var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            x: 'x',

            columns: [
                ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ],
             types : {
                  'data1': 'area'
                }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

However if I just move the 'data1' to a variable, it no longer fills..

```
var val = 'data1';
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    x: 'x',

    columns: [
        ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ],
     types : {
          val: 'area'  // <---- USING VARIABLE
        }
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
    }
   }
   });
```

Does anyone have any idea about why this should make any difference, and if there is a workaround?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I guess your config is going to use 'val' as key instead of the value of val.

Workaround:

```
var val = 'data1';
var conf = {
data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
        ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
        [val, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ],
    types : {}
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
    }
   }
   }

conf.data.types[val] = 'area';
var chart = c3.generate(conf);
```

Btw you forgot to change another variable.

```
columns [ ..., ['data1',...]]
```